# mysql not using index?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table with columns like word, A_, E_, U_ .. these columns with X_ are tinyints having the value of how many times the specific letter exists in the word (to later help optimize the wildcard search query).

There is totally 252k rows. If i make search like WHERE u_ > 0 i get 60k rows. But if i do the explain of that select, it says there is 225k rows to go through and no index possible. Why? Column was added as index. Why it doesn't say there is 60k rows to go through and that possible key is U_?

[image]

listing the indexes on table (also strange that others are groupped under A_ index)

[image]

In comparison if i run query: where id > 250000 i get 2983 results, and if i do explain of that select it says there is 2982 rows and key to be used primary.

Btw if i group by U_ i get this: (but probably doesnt matter much because i already said the query returns 60k results)

[image]

**EDIT:**

If i create column U (varchar(1)) and do the update U = 'U' where U_ > 0, then if i do the select WHERE U = 'U' i get also 60k rows (obviously), but if i do explain i get this:

[image]

Still not so good (rows 120k not 60k) but at least better than rows 225k in previous case. Although this solution is bit more piggy that than the first one, but maybe bit more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking about the backend query optimizer. In particular you're asking: "how does it choose an access path? Why index here but tablescan there?"

Let's think about that optimizer. What is it optimizing? Elapsed time, in expectation. It has a model for how long sequential reads and random reads take, and for query selectivity, that is, expected number of rows returned by a query. From several alternative access paths it chooses the one that appears to require the least elapsed time.

Your `id > 250000` query had a few things going for it:

1. good selectivity, so less than 1% of rows will appear in the result set
2. `id` is the Primary Key, so all columns are immediately available upon navigating to the right place in the btree

This caused the optimizer to compute an expected elapsed time for the indexed access path much smaller than expected time for tablescan.

On the other hand, your `u_ > 0` query has very poor selectivity, dragging nearly a quarter of the rows into the result set. Additionally, the index is not a covering index for your `*` demand of copying *all* column values into the result set. So the optimizer predicts it will have to read a quarter of the index blocks, and then essentially all of the data row blocks that they point to. So compared to tablescan, we'd have to read *more* blocks from disk, *and* they would be random reads instead of sequential reads. Both of those argue against using the index, so tablescan was selected because it was cheapest. Also, remember that often multiple rows will fit within a single disk block, or within a single read request. We would call it a pessimizer if it always chose the indexed access path, even in cases where indexed disk I/O would take longer.

## summary advice

Use an index on a single column when your queries have good selectivity, returning much less than 1% of a relation's rows. Use a [covering index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index#Covering_index) when your queries have poor selectivity and you're willing to make a space vs. time tradeoff.

Comment: Hello. If i add index on column i expect it will drastically speed up the the "access path" and that it will also state in describe query that the index will be used and that the total count of scanned rows will be smaller. Namely in this case i expect that mysql will have precreated groups of rows by values of U_ and in fact there will be no need of scanning of other rows with other values. But explain query says something other. It says it will use NO index, and that number of rows to scan is basically all rows. What's the point of index then.

Comment: The "precreated groups of rows by values of u_" goes by the name "covering index". Your EXPLAIN output is telling you that u_ is indexed, but it's not a covering index, so it doesn't offer the cheapest access path. If you only asked for `select u_, e_ from ...`, after creating a compound index on (u_, e_), that may convince the optimizer to choose a different access path. BTW, notice that a narrow slice of just a handful of columns will fit in fewer disk blocks, so even a blind query (no selectivity) may prefer a covering index over tablescan of the base rows.

Comment: You are right that if i do EXPLAIN SELECT u_ FROM `words` where u_ > 0 it uses U_ as index and the number of rows is 120k (as with force index). Good to know.

Answer (score 3):

My experience is that MySQL chooses to do a tablescan, even if there is an index on the column you're searching, if your query would select more than approximately 25% of the rows in the table.

The reason for this is that using a secondary index in InnoDB is a bit more work than using a primary index.

1. Look up value in secondary index, like your index on `u_`.
2. Read index entry, and find corresponding primary key value(s) of rows where that value in `u_` is stored.
3. Look up row(s) by primary key.

It's actually at least *double* the work to look up by secondary key. This isn't a problem if you ultimately match a small minority of rows of the table, and there are definitely cases where a secondary index is really important for your query. So don't be reluctant to use secondary indexes.

But if your query matches too many rows, and that becomes a big portion of the table, then it would be less work to just scan the table start-to-finish.

By analogy, why doesn't the index at the back of a book contain the word "the"? Because the entry would naturally list *every single page in the book*, and it would be a waste for you to refer to the index and then use it to guide you to each page in the main part of the book. You would have been better off just reading the book.

MySQL does not have any officially documented threshold for choosing a tablescan over an indexed search. The 25% figure is only my experience (actually sometimes it seems closer to 21%, but I don't know the code well enough to understand exactly how the threshold is calculated).

I've seen cases where the proportion of rows matched was very close to whatever threshold is in the implementation, and the behavior of the optimizer can actually flip-flop from one query to the next, resulting in highly variable performance.

If this case applies to you, you can use an [index hint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html) to make MySQL's optimizer pretend that a tablescan is prohibitively expensive, and it should prefer an index to a tablescan. This is done with the `FORCE INDEX` hint.

```
SELECT * FROM words FORCE INDEX(U_) WHERE U_ > 0
```

I still try to use index hints conservatively. They aren't necessary except in rare cases, and using an index hint means your query must include the index name. This makes it hard to change indexes without breaking your application code.

Comment: Hello Bill. Nice example with the "the" word. Thank you for reply too. With force index (u_) it really uses that index and number of rows is 120k, so to me it seems better than go through 250k, but force is maybe unusable once i combine multiple conditions (columns) then is probably better to let the optimizer decide what to do (as you say), but thanks for the info.

Comment: MySQL 8.0 (and MariaDB 10.0) have "histograms" that will 'solve' this issue with unbalanced indexing.

Comment: @RickJames this is not an issue caused by imbalanced indexes. One can run a query that matches > 25% of an index even if the index is UNIQUE.