# Why the index on my MySQL table is not being used?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a table in MySQL (InnoDB engine) with 100M records. Structure is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE LEDGER_AGR (
    ID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Booking` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `LType` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    `PType` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    `FType` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
    `TType` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `AccountCode` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
    `AgAccountId` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
    `TransactionDate` date NOT NULL,
    `DebitAmt` decimal(37,6) DEFAULT '0.000000',
    `CreditAmt` decimal(37,6) DEFAULT '0.000000',
    KEY `TRANSACTION_DATE` (`TransactionDate`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

When I am doing:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM LEDGER_AGR
WHERE TransactionDate >= '2000-08-01'
  AND TransactionDate <= '2017-08-01'
```

It is not using `TRANSACTION_DATE` index.  But when I am doing:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM LEDGER_AGR
WHERE TransactionDate = '2000-08-01'
```

it *is* using `TRANSACTION_DATE` index.  Could someone explain please?

Answer (score 1):

Range query #1 has poor selectivity. Equality query #2 has excellent selectivity. The optimizer is very likely to choose the index access path when result rows will be < 1% of total rows in table. The backend optimizer is unlikely to prefer the index when result rows will be a large fraction of the total, for example a half or a quarter of all rows.

A range of '2000-08-01' thru '2000-08-03' would likely exploit the index.

cf: [mysql not using index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46757781/mysql-not-using-index#answer-46757936)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But even the below query is doing full table scan.EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM LEDGER_AGR
WHERE TransactionDate >= '2017-08-01'
  AND TransactionDate <= '2017-09-01' The output of this will be small fraction of the total, hence I was expecting its explain plan to use TRANSACTION_DATE index, but unfortunately it is still doing full table scan.

Comment: Define "small" fraction, please. That is, do binary search on the ~32 days of August, and tell us at how many days and at what percent of rows it switches from tablescan. Also, consider asking for a narrower slice via a covering index, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index#Covering_index . E.g. create new index on (TransactionDate, DebitAmt) in that order, and instead of "select *" ask for "select TransactionDate, DebitAmt..."