# MySQL - Basic index slowing down simple aggregate query

Tags: mysql, indexing

I've a simple table where we store traffic data:

```
CREATE TABLE `domain_traffic` (
  `dtraff_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `domain_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `dtraff_time` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `dtraff_web` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0',
  `dtraff_ftp` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0',
  `dtraff_mail` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0',
  `dtraff_pop` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `domain_traffic`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`dtraff_id`),
  ADD KEY `domain_id` (`domain_id`);

ALTER TABLE `domain_traffic`
  MODIFY `dtraff_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Running the following query by forcing usage of the **domain_id** index (what MySQL is doing by default) tooks ~ 12 seconds:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
    SUM(dtraff_web) as web,
    SUM(dtraff_ftp) as ftp,
    SUM(dtraff_mail) as mail,
    SUM(dtraff_pop) as pop
FROM domain_traffic FORCE INDEX (domain_id)
WHERE domain_id = 150
```

BUT

The same query above by asking MySQL to ignore the **domain_id** index tooks only ~ 2 seconds (which is still bad anyway):

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
    SUM(dtraff_web) as web,
    SUM(dtraff_ftp) as ftp,
    SUM(dtraff_mail) as mail,
    SUM(dtraff_pop) as pop
FROM domain_traffic IGNORE INDEX (domain_id)
WHERE domain_id = 150
```

I'm really suprised about such result and I'm really wondering why this occurs...

**EXPLAIN** for both queries:

USING **domain_id** INDEX:

```
+------+-------------+----------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table          | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra |
+------+-------------+----------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | domain_traffic | ref  | domain_id     | domain_id | 4       | const | 2069312 |       |
+------+-------------+----------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+-------+
```

IGNORING **domain_id** INDEX

```
+------+-------------+----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table          | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | domain_traffic | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 4138625 | Using where |
+------+-------------+----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------
```

For the record:

1. MySQL vendor: MariaDB 10.1
2. Number of rows for domain with ID 150: 4156659

Any explanation and advise?

Thank you.

Result without optimizer hints (following @Bill Karwin answer):

```
MariaDB [imscp]> EXPLAIN
  SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
          SUM(dtraff_web) as web, SUM(dtraff_ftp) as ftp,
          SUM(dtraff_mail) as mail, SUM(dtraff_pop) as pop
      FROM domain_traffic WHERE domain_id = 150;
+------+-------------+----------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table          | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra |
+------+-------------+----------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | domain_traffic | ref  | domain_id     | domain_id | 4       | const | 2069312 |       |
+------+-------------+----------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [imscp]> SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
      SUM(dtraff_web) as web, SUM(dtraff_ftp) as ftp,
      SUM(dtraff_mail) as mail, SUM(dtraff_pop) as pop
  FROM domain_traffic WHERE domain_id = 150;
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| web          | ftp          | mail         | pop          |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 105989792928 | 106045788277 | 105954990092 | 105942540350 |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
1 row in set (8.53 sec)
```

Comment: This question is very similar, but not quite a duplicate, of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46757781/mysql-not-using-index/46758591#46758591

Comment: It seems extremely unlikely that those 4 numbers would be that close to identical.  Recommend you check their validity.  (mail and pop makes sense, but not the others.)

Comment: @RickJames These are closely identical because I created the rows with rand for testing purpose.

Comment: @Nuxwin - Hehe, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you actually time it both ways?  It probably ran faster when it *ignored* the index.  (And Bill explains why.)

If you want to speed up the query, read on...

The problem is that the rows needed to satisfy the query are scattered -- either arranged randomly, or with junk in between, or both.  The solution is to rearrange the data so that you need read only the desired data, and even avoid using a secondary index.

```
`dtraff_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`domain_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
...
PRIMARY KEY(domain_id, dtraff_time, dtraff_id)
INDEX(dtraff_id)
```

The `PRIMARY KEY` (in InnoDB) forces the data to be in the desired order.  In your case, that will clump all 2M rows `WHERE domain_id = 150` next to each other, and let you read *only* them, even *without* using the extra lookup that a secondary index requires.

The `INDEX(dtraff_id)` is necessary (and sufficient) to appease `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: Well, real query has a WHERE clause such as WHERE domain_id = 150 AND dtraff_time BETWEEN <timestamp> AND <timestamp>. Is your sentence still valid with range condition?

Comment: I changed my recommendation to accommodate your revised WHERE.

Answer (score 2):

When you have the EXPLAIN that ignores the index, it shows it runs a table scan (type: ALL). The rows examined is ~4.1m (which is only a rough estimate anyway, not an accurate count).

You clarified that there are ~4.1m rows with domain_id = 150. So, practically every row in the table matches your WHERE condition.

Think of an index at the back of a book. Why doesn't it contain entries for words like "the" or "and"? Because those words appear on virtually every page, and it would be a waste of time to index them, and to use the index to find occurrences of those common words, flip to the respective page, then flip back to the index to find the next occurrence is on page 2, and so on.

It's the same way with a secondary index in MySQL. If the optimizer detects that a given value you search for is too common, it skips the index and just does a table-scan. It's easier to do that when reading an index when the index won't effectively narrow down the search enough to make it worthwhile.

In practice, I've observed that the optimizer skips using the index when the value occurs on 21-25% of rows in the table. Usually this is a good call. Rarely, it's necessary to use FORCE INDEX to tell the optimizer that you don't want a table-scan at all costs. But that's rare.

My advice is: **Let the optimizer do its job.** It will usually make a good decision about whether to use an index, based on the query logic *and* the frequency of the specific value you're searching for.

---

Re your comment:

If your production data allows the WHERE condition to select a minority subset of your table, then the optimizer should decide that it's worth using the index. One of the optimizer's goals is to reduce the number of *examined rows* that InnoDB needs to read.

This is a good example of why you need to test with data that mimics your production data. Having the right ratios of different data values helps you do a realistic query optimizer tests.

Also make sure you use [ANALYZE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html) from time to time to make sure InnoDB has current stats about data distribution in the index. I've seen cases where odd index behavior was fixed very simply by running ANALYZE TABLE. It's a quick operation, even if your table is very large.

This doesn't have to be very frequent, but if the distribution of values in your index changes dramatically (like if you do a major bulk insert or bulk delete), it's worth doing ANALYZE TABLE afterwards.

Comment: That was for the example. The optimizer (without forcing usage of index) is still using it. See at bottom of my answer. I've added the statements without index hints. And yes, here all records belong to domain with ID 150 but that not case on production where there are several domains and where we also retrieve data for a given time period, using range (between).