# MySQL index work in one table and not work in another table when using IN

Tags: mysql, database-indexes

I was asked if the index is working or not when we use `IN` keyword in `MySQL` like below:

```
 //suppose col has index and the value is almost unique
 SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE col IN('xxx','yyy','zzz');
```

In order to get the accurate result, I do the test myself,I created two tables,and index works on one table but not work on another table,I do not know why.Hope someone helps me understand it.Thanks in advance.

The first table is called `system_users` :

```
CREATE TABLE system_users(
  id INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  NAME CHAR(15),
  gender CHAR(1),
  age INT(2),
  department CHAR(1),
  email VARCHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE INDEX name_index ON system_users(NAME);

INSERT  INTO system_users(id,NAME,gender,age,department,email) 
  VALUES 
(1,'euser_izpwhzzcz','1',37,'1','yvmk0oqm0lf@mail.com'),
(2,'muser_czepyfklv','1',20,'1','a9wq08gcllk@mail.com'),
(3,'tuser_mwrluajek','0',20,'1','o8jqqebi0bt@mail.com'),
(4,'duser_jzgpheafx','0',22,'2','hegehgsbfmg@mail.com'),
(5,'auser_iacjkekhg','0',36,'2','46drnrja29i@mail.com'),
(6,'euser_eikhwvwsi','1',31,'2','56amq6nayde@mail.com'),
(7,'muser_lblozikah','1',29,'3','qlbtvpzgrej@mail.com'),
(8,'cuser_xhsuuzzur','0',35,'3','klrr6kurylg@mail.com'),
(9,'vuser_iwmklbyzp','0',22,'3','ngdrlguhzrp@mail.com'),
(10,'buser_yfnffsfoc','0',37,'4','o1jvffj4ahu@mail.com');
```

Now,when I use `EXPLAIN` to analysis below query sql,I found the index works

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM system_users WHERE NAME IN('euser_eikhwvwsi','buser_yfnffsfoc');
```

**As we see the value of `type` is `range`,in this scenario index seems works when use `IN`**
[image: Index work when use IN]

---

The second table is called `test`:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  c1 VARCHAR(10),
  c2 VARCHAR(10),
  c3 VARCHAR(10),
  c4 VARCHAR(10),
  c5 VARCHAR(10)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE INDEX c_index ON test(c1);

INSERT INTO test(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) VALUES('a1','a2','a3','a4','a5');
INSERT INTO test(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) VALUES('b1','b2','b3','b4','b5');
INSERT INTO test(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) VALUES('c1','c2','c3','c4','c5');
INSERT INTO test(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) VALUES('d1','d2','d3','d4','d5');
INSERT INTO test(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) VALUES('e1','e2','e3','e4','e5');

INSERT INTO test(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) VALUES('a1','b1','c1','d1','e1');
INSERT INTO test(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) VALUES('b1','a2','b2','b4','b5');
INSERT INTO test(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) VALUES('c1','a3','c3','d4','c5');
INSERT INTO test(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) VALUES('d1','a4','d3','d4','d5');
INSERT INTO test(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) VALUES('e1','a5','b5','e4','e5');
```

Now when I use `EXPLAIN` to analysis below sql,**the index seem not work since the `value` of type is `all`**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test WHERE c1 IN('a1','b1');
```

[image: Index not work when use IN]

**Both of the two tables has ordinary column and datas,but when use `IN`,why the `type` of one is `range` while the other is `all`?**

PS:The version of `MySQL` in my side is **`5.0.67`**,I have run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` for both table and still get the same result.

Below are the result when execute `ANALYZE TABLE`

[image]

Comment: Tests on tables with 10 rows can be misleading. Also, in your 2nd query, you get 40% of the rows as a resultset. In this case, a full table scan can be a good choice, but unless this represents the actual data distribution, it can easily be misleasing too.

Comment: @Solarflare I just insert 10 records for simply,the amount of the data is not the issue,I just want to know why index works different in these two tables

Comment: Well, in that case is comes down to MySQL deciding that 40% of rows is too much to read via index lookup, see e.g. [mysql not using index?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46757781)

Comment: @Solarflare Seems you are right,I tested it and when I increase the data amount,the value of `type` will change to `range`,thanks